# Setting a custom header using PHP

Tags: php, email, header, smtp, send

I am using phpmailer for sending emails, but I want to make a custom header for my campaign, by adding a textarea field that contain any custom header here is my code but I don't know where is the problem it not working I don't see my custom header in mail full header:

```
foreach (preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $_POST['customHeader']) as $line) {
    list($name, $value) = explode(': ', $line, 2);
    $PHPMailer->addCustomHeader($name,$value);
}
```

Even I use different headers, I don't see  my custom header in recieved mail, please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To split the line just use explode, and trim it, also phpmailer will split itself if skip value.

```
$items = explode(chr(10), $_POST['customHeader']);
foreach($items as $line)
    $PHPMailer->addCustomHeader(trim($line));
```